# Is this code wrong to call the same constructor more than once

Tags: java

The object that is created by the constructor in the following code can be called multiple times. Have I written the code badly by doing so I hope it is written to the proper conventions

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 * this class uses the scanner to take input from the keyboard
 * test if the input is a variable of type double if it is store in a 
 * variable called numOne then take next input test again for type double
 * store in variable numTwo, then add the two variables together in the form
 * of variable answer and return to the screen. The user then is asked for
 * continuation as Y/N then appropriate action is taken
 */

public class Calc {

    /**
     * this constructer does not throw InputMismatchException
     */

    public Calc() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);  // create scanner object

        System.out.println("please enter 1st " 
            + "number then press enter"
                + "\nthen enter 2nd number then " 
            + "press enter again");

        /*test for a double returns true */
        boolean myBool = in.hasNextDouble();

        /*the actual test for a double*/
        if(myBool == false) {    
                System.out.println("wrong format");

           /**
            * call constructer and instantiate as new object
            * by creating a new object i hope to have overwriten
            * the original object stored in memory there by getting
            * around the problem of hasNextDouble not allowing the
            * scanner to advance
            */

                Calc c = new Calc();

        } else {                   // 1st else
                double numOne = in.nextDouble();       // keyboard input

            /*test for a double returns true */
                boolean myBool2 = in.hasNextDouble();

        /*the actual test for a double*/
        if(myBool2 == false) {
                System.out.println("wrong format start again");

           /**
            * call constructer and instantiate as new object
            * there by removing need for InputMismatchException
            */

                Calc c = new Calc();

        } else {                   // 2nd else
                double numTwo = in.nextDouble();       // keyboard input

                double answer = numOne + numTwo;       // the maths

        for(int i = 0; i<35; i++) {            // print pattern
                System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("\n****  " 
            + "Your 1st number is " 
            + numOne + "   ****");

        System.out.println("****     "        // print operator
            + "                   " + "+" 
            + "   ****");

        System.out.println("****  " 
            + "Your 2nd number is " 
            + numTwo + "   ****");

        System.out.println("****     "       // print line
            + "               ______  ****");

        System.out.println("****       " 
            + "The answer is " 
            + answer + "   ****");

        for(int i = 0; i<35; i++) {         //print pattern
                System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("\nDo you have " 
            + "more calculations Y or N");

        String reply = in.next();                //keyboard input

        if(reply.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
                Calc c = new Calc();
        } else {
                System.out.println("OK bye then");
                in.close();             //close scanner
        }               //end else
        }   // end 1st else
        }   // end 2nd else
        }   // end constructor

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calc c = new Calc();            // call constructor
    }  // end main
}    // end class

// just in case i do something wrong thanks in anticipation  Simon.
```

Comment: Please put more effort into formatting your code. It's all over the place at the moment... then put in some more effort to ask a question. You've included a *lot* of code, but only talked generically about "the object that is created by the constructor" - which object? Which constructor?

Comment: It seems like a pretty horrible idea.  I don't know that it's technically "wrong," but I think a lot of folks would call it wrong in production code.

Comment: If we ignore the infinite loop, the question is: Why the entire program is inside the constructor? WTF. The constructor should be used to create the object, not to execute the program.

Comment: Hi guys I am fairly new to any type of coding and I do appreciate the input from every one.Now @Jon Skeet could you be more specific in your comment as to all over the place as this would be of great help to me and others, also could you point out all the other constructors as I genuinely thought there was only one 'public Calc()' being called by 'new Calc()' first by the main method and 2 more times if and only if the user did not enter a double.

Comment: @Marco Acierno could you please point out the infinite loop as I do not honestly see one also could you elaborate on program execution as I thought this was done by the main method I put it in a constructor so I could call it from another class could you show me how to make it into a method please.

Comment: `Calc c = new Calc();` is potentially a infinite loop which will remains all the `Calc` objects uninitialized. And, your entire logic inside the constructor (BAD) Just move it in the main method and use constructor to initialize fields

Comment: @SimonRemington: Look at the indentation of the code - specifically, the first few lines of the constructor. `Scanner in...` isn't indented... whereas the next statement *is* indented, by 4 spaces. Elsewhere things are indented by 8 spaces. (If you're using tabs, please don't for SO - it doesn't work well.) Basically, it's up to you as the person asking the question to make the code as readable as possible... and ideally as *short* as possible to demonstrate the problem, while remaining complete.

Answer (score 2):

Calling the constructor from within the same constructor, and without any parameters, looks like a sure way to get infinite loop and stack overflow. So, yes, it's wrong.

And since it doesn't look as if you are doing anything with all the instances of `Calc` that you create within the constructor, it's pointless.

Comment: Hi Eran the reason I recall public Calc(), if a user does not enter a double I could not get past .hasNextDouble as the scanner did not seem to advance the input. So I created a new object and started again please point out the possible loop.

Comment: @SimonRemington It doesn't make sense to put all this code in a constructor at all, since you are not really constructing an object, you are just getting inputs from the user and print some outputs. I'd put all this code in a static method. And instead of the recursive calls, put all the code in a while loop - `boolean needInput=true;while (needInput) {}`. Inside the loop, in any place you currently call the constructor, replace it with `continue`, which would proceed to the new iteration of the loop. set `needInput` to false when you which to quit the program.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually seen as bad practice to do any work in a constructor that is not directly related to instantiating that object. Consider moving your logic into another method on the `Calc`. That way you can use a single instance of `Calc`, and using fields on that instance you might have better luck overwriting the values your comments mention that you want to overwrite.

As Eran mentioned, your current pattern uses recursive calls, which are prone to stack overflows if not done right. I wouldn't go so far as to say recursive calls are always a bad thing, but you should carefully consider whether that's the best pattern for what you're doing.

Comment: hello StriplingWarrior thank you for your input, in your opinion is the logic correct? and is there another way to make the scanner advance past .hasNextDouble. The reason behind the logic is that I read it is better to write code that does not throw errors than to rely on catching them.

Comment: @SimonRemington: developers will often use a loop to accomplish what you're describing: `while(true) { if(!in.hasNextDouble()){ outputNoNumberError(); break; } double numOne = in.nextDouble(); ... }`. As to whether the logic is correct, I'm not familiar with what your requirements are, and I don't feel like analyzing dozens of lines of code. That's not the purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0):

Although you (probably) won't get an error, this is bad practice in many ways.

First of all, you should not do any of this in a constructor. A constructor is supposed to create an object or throw an Exception, that's it. If the constructor requires any input, read it in advance and pass it as an argument to the constructor. **Constructors are not made for user interaction.**

The next point is error handling. If the user makes an invalid input, there is absolutely no need to use recursion. Sure, you won't get a StackOverflowError (unless your user fails a few thousand times), but a loop is a better solution.

```
System.out.print("Enter a double please: ");
while(!scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
    System.out.print("Invalid input. Please try again: ");
    scanner.next(); //discard invalid input
}
double input = scanner.nextDouble();
```

Comment: J4v4 can you elaborate on your loop please, as when I compile the one that you have posted, it only produces an endless loop for me when I do not enter a double or is this a humorous way of creating a StackOverflowError. Please show me this loop so I do not get an InputMismatchException thank you

Comment: @Simon Remington I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with scanner so I didn't use the methods correctly. I looked it up now and fixed it.